# Fibonacci Iteration : To find the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence for n > 50

Tags: java, iteration, fibonacci

This code doesn't return correct answer after n = 46. What can i do to fix this to get higher nth term?

```
 public static long fibonacciIterative(long n) 
    {
      if(n <= 1) {
    return n;
           }
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        for(int i=2; i<n; i++) 
           {
            int z = x;
            x+= y;
            y = z;
            }
        return x;
}
```

Thank you all for your positive feedback. I figured it out as soon as i ran down the code after asking the question.

Comment: Start by changing `x`, `y` and `z` to `long`.

Comment: HINT: What do you think is the maximum number `int` can represent? How big do you think Fibonacci numbers are beyond 46?

Comment: `int` holds numbers from **-2^31** up to **2^31-1**, since `int` is represented by 32 bits in Java. Any fibonacci number n>46 term is above those limits. You can use a `long` which is 64 bits and holds larger numbers.  `BigInteger` holds even larger, if you have a need to exceed the limits of a `long`.

Comment: @Henry True thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because of integer overflow. Use `long` for the variables `x`, `y` and `z`.

This will bring you a bit further, but will eventually also overflow the `long` range. If you need still larger numbers, go for `BigInteger`.

Answer (score -1):

The most optimal way, with a complexity of `O(1)` would be Binet's Formula, which in Java is as follows:

```
 static long fibonacciBinet(long n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    double sqrt5 = Math.sqrt(5);
    long x = (long) ((Math.pow(1+sqrt5, n)-Math.pow(1-sqrt5, n))/(Math.pow(2, n)*sqrt5));

    return x;
}
```